# Navigation bar floats when filling out form on a smartphone

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I have a fixed nav bar which works perfectly on the desktop, responsinator, etc.  When I attempt to fill out a form field on my iPhone, the navigation bar mysteriously floats; when I scroll up or down it stays in the middle of the screen.

[image: screenshot showing the described problem]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  My code is available here [and on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MaxGimmeChefs/nv2g7stf/).

```js
    $(function () {
    var pull = $('#pull');
    menu = $('nav ul');
    menuHeight = menu.height();

    $(pull).on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });

    $('nav li>a').on('click', function (e) {
        if ($(window).width() < 600) {
            menu.slideUp();
        }
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        var w = $(window).width();
        if (w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
    });
```

```css
/* Clearfix */

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {

    content:" ";

    display: table;

}

.clearfix:after {

    clear: both;

}

.clearfix {

    *zoom: 1;

}

/* Basic Styles */

nav {

    height:42px;

    top: 0;

    position: fixed;

    border-bottom: 2px solid #e1e1e1;

    width: 100%;

    margin: 0px auto;

    background: #e63333;

    font-size: 105%;

    font-weight: 400;

    text-align: center;

    z-index:99;

}

nav ul {

    padding: 2px;

    margin: 0 auto;

    width: auto;

    height: 40px;

}

nav li {

    display: inline;

    float: none;

}

nav a {

    color: #fff;

    display: inline-block;

    width: 80px;

    text-decoration: none;

    line-height: 40px;

}

nav li:last-child a {

    border-right: 0;

}

nav a:hover, nav a:active {

    background-color: #f95f5f;

}

nav a#pull {

    display: none;

}

/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    nav {

        height:auto;

        top: 0;

        background-color:#e35f5f;

    }

    nav ul {

        width: 100%;

        display: block;

        height: auto;

    }

    nav li {

        width: 50%;

        float: left;

        position: relative;

    }

    nav li a {

    }

    nav a {

        text-align: left;

        width: 100%;

        text-indent: 25px;

    }

}

/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    nav {

        border-bottom: 0;

        background-color:#e35f5f;

    }

    nav ul {

        display: none;

        height: auto;

    }

    nav a#pull {

        display: block;

        background-color: #e63333;

        width: 100%;

        position: relative;

        box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #888888;

    }

    nav a#pull:after {

        content:"";

        background: url('../images/nav-icon.png') no-repeat;

        width: 30px;

        height: 30px;

        display: inline-block;

        position: absolute;

        right: 15px;

        top: 10px;

    }

}

/*Smartphone*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {

    nav li {

        width: 50%;

        float: left;

    }

    nav li a {

        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;

    }

}

/* End Clearfix */

/* Chef Registration Form */

:-moz-placeholder {

    font-size: 105%;

    font-weight: 400;

}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {

    font-size: 105%;

    font-weight: 400;

}

*:focus {

    outline: none;

}

.form {

    margin: 10px auto;

    width:60.5%;

    height:auto;

    background-color: #e6e6e6;

    border: 1px solid #b9afaf;

    text-decoration: none;

    border-radius: 5px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    -ms-border-radius: 5px;

    -o-border-radius: 5px;

    padding-left: 2.5%;

    padding-top: 20px;

}

.form input {

    width: 90%;

    padding: 8px 0 8px 8px;

    margin-left: 12px;

    list-style-type: none;

    border-radius: 5px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    -ms-border-radius: 5px;

    -o-border-radius: 5px;

    border: 1px solid #ccccff;

    background: #fafafa;

}

.form button {

    width: 91%;

    margin-bottom: 8px;

    margin-left: 15px;

}

.form li {

    padding-bottom:8px;

    position:relative;

    list-style-type: none;

}

.form textarea {

    max-width: 90%;

    min-width: 90%;

    padding: 4px 0 4px 8px;

    margin-left: 12px;

}

.form input, .form textarea {

    border:1px solid #aaa;

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #ccc, 0 10px 15px #fafafa inset;

}

.form input:focus, .form textarea:focus {

    background: #fff;

    border:1px solid #6699ff;

    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa;

    list-style-type: none;

}

/* Button Style */

button.submit {

    background-color: #e63333;

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,    from(#e43535), to(#e63333));

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e43535, #e63333);

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e43535, #e63333);

    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e43535, #e63333);

    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e43535, #e63333);

    background: linear-gradient(top, #e43535, #e63333);

    border: 1px solid #888888;

    border-bottom: 1px solid #888888;

    border-radius: 5px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    -ms-border-radius: 5px;

    -o-border-radius: 5px;

    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #888888;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #888888 inset;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #888888 inset;

    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #888888 inset;

    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #888888 inset;

    color: white;

    font-weight: 400;

    font-size: 105%;

    padding: 6px 20px;

    text-align: center;

}

button.submit:hover {

    opacity:.85;

    cursor: pointer;

}

button.submit:active {

    border: 1px solid #303030;

    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888888 inset;

    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px 2px #888888 inset;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #888888 inset;

    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #888888 inset;

    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #888888 inset;

}

/* End of Chef Registration Form */
```

```html
    <nav class="clearfix">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href=""><span style="color:white">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#rates"><span style="color:white">Rates</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#pay"><span style="color:white">Pay</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#buy"><span style="color:white">Buyout</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#join"><span style="color:white">Join</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact"><span style="color:white">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul> <a href="#" id="pull"><span style="color:white">Menu</span></a>

    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use the position: fixed; use position: absolute; instead.

```
nav {
        height:42px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #e1e1e1;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px auto;
        background: #e63333;
        font-size: 105%;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-align: center;
        z-index:99;

    }
```

Comment: Nope... No good. position: absolute means the nav bar is not fixed to the top of the screen as you scroll down on the smart phone.  Which is what I want.